# not storing data to database in MySQL, can you tell me the mistake or changes

Tags: php, mysql

in this code.in this code awmb is database name and Email, Name, RegNo, Password, cellno, Branch are attributs of table users.

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include("connection.php");
        if(isset($_POST['reg_submit'])&&($dbhandle))
        {
            mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('awmb',$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());
            $Email=$_GET['Email'];
            $Name=$_GET['Name'];
            $RegNo=$_GET['RegisterNo'];
            $Password=$_GET['Password'];
            $cellno=$_GET['PhoneNo'];
            $Branch=$_GET['branch'];
            if($Email!="" && $Name!="" && $RegNo!="" && $Password!="" && $cellno!="" && $Branch!="" )
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO users (Email,Name,RegNo,Password,cellno,Branch) VALUES ($Email,$Name,$RegNo,$Password,$cellno,$Branch)";
                if(!mysql_query($sql,$dbhandle))
                {
                    die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['Email']=$Email;
                    header("location:profile.php");
                }
            }
        }
        mysql_close($dbhandle);
    ?>
```

Comment: use mysqli_* because mysql_* is deprcated.

Comment: is form action is POST or GET. you used `$_POST['reg_submit']` and `$_GET['Email']`

Comment: also wrap variables in single quotes in VALUES section of your query string

Comment: Oh dear, I do hope this code is not live. You have a serious SQL injection vulnerability here, _and_ you're storing passwords in plain text. It may be worth finding a good book or tutorial to see how to do this properly.

Comment: No response from peoples asking question, even after asking. frustrating. deleting my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO users (Email,Name,RegNo,Password,cellno,Branch) VALUES ('$Email','$Name','$RegNo','$Password','$cellno','$Branch')
```

Instead

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO users (Email,Name,RegNo,Password,cellno,Branch) VALUES ($Email,$Name,$RegNo,$Password,$cellno,$Branch)
```

Also use either GET OR POST whatever your form post type.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to make the query insert the data is wrap your variables inside VALUES clause in INSERT query with single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO users (Email,Name,RegNo,Password,cellno,Branch) VALUES ('$Email', '$Name', '$RegNo', '$Password', '$cellno', '$Branch')
```

Also note following things:

- You should use either MySQLi or PDO. Never use MySQL, because its deprecated and will be removed very soon from PHP.
- Why have you included connection.php? You should put your mysql_connect code in that file itself.